# Use multiple values from a form into where condition in yii2 framework php

Tags: php, sql, yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am trying to fetch values using where() query in yii2, I want to use multiple where conditions from which values will be fetched, I have tried several alternatives none of them seems to work.

The number and contents of $values is varying

```
$test = Material::find()->where(['Material.MaterialId' => $value])->joinWith(['objectName'])->all();
```

This one works for single value. But if i do a foreach loop to get all the variation values. So I get a string like

```
$values = "'ID1','ID2','ID3','IDn',";
$test = Material::find()->where('in', 'Material.MaterialId' , [$values])->joinWith(['objectName'])->all();
```

It Returns Nothing But If I use is like that

```
$test = Material::find()->where('in', 'Material.MaterialId' , [ID1','ID2','ID3','IDn',])->joinWith(['objectName'])->all();
```

This gets me the required results. I have also tried the same using or in where clause and orWhere method, I guess all are having same problem.

Comment: I haven't used the framework but if you have `$values` as an array and do `where('in', 'Material.MaterialId' , $values)`, would that not work?

Comment: I have tried using it as an array like that `$test = Material::find()->where('in', 'Material.MaterialId' , [$values])->joinWith(['objectName'])->all();`

Where values is an array too. 
But I just tried it like that 

`$test = Material::find()->where('in', 'Material.MaterialId' , $values)->joinWith(['objectName'])->all();`

and It worked. Thanks Mate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this way

```
$value = [' ID1','ID2','ID3','IDn'];

$test = Material::find()->where(['Material.MaterialId' => $value])->
   joinWith(['objectName'])->all();
```